# Delphi - error with recursive array function to generate combinations of (1 and 0)

Tags: delphi, recursion

I'm attempting to write a recursive function returning all combinations of (1 and 0) for a certain depth (so if maxdepth is 1 I want (1) and (0) and if it's 2 I want (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1) etc. but I keep getting an access violation (Read of address 00000000). Here's the code:

```
function binom(depth,maxdepth:integer):specarr;
var
  i,j,k:integer;
  a:specarr;
begin
  setlength(result,0);
  if depth<maxdepth then begin
    a:=binom(depth+1,maxdepth);
    for i:=0 to 1 do begin
      for j:=0 to length(a)-1 do begin
        setlength(result,length(result)+1);
        setlength(result[length(result)-1],length(a[0])+1);
        result[length(result)-1,0]:=i;
        for k:=1 to length(a[0]) do begin
          result[length(result)-1,k]:=a[j,k-1];
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end else begin
    Setlength(result,2);
    Setlength(result[0],1);
    Setlength(result[1],1);
    result[0,0]:=1;
    result[0,1]:=0;
  end;
end;
```

called by this code:

```
var
  ab:specarr;
begin
  ab:=binom(1,1);
```

where specarr is defined as

```
type
  specarr = array of array of integer;
```

Sorry in advance for the messy code.

Comment: for i:=0 to 0 do begin

Comment: Oh yes, it's supposed to be for i:=0 to 1, I was just testing if it worked with 0 to 0, but the problem exists with both of them; I've changed it now

Comment: in the latest part, you should have 

    Setlength(result,2);
    Setlength(result[0],1);
    Setlength(result[1],1);
    result[0,0]:=1;
    result[1,0]:=0;

Comment: This does not look promising. `result[0,1]:=0;` is wrong. That's off the end of the array. And `for k:=1 to length(a[0]) do begin` sends `k` off the end too.

Comment: Thanks, hugo, that was it. I wouldn't have caught that without your help, it works fine now.

Comment: Sorry, the for loop is fine. More broadly, this kind of code is dreadfully hard to understand. All that inline resizing and repeated use of Length. Seek to make the code more readable and clear.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, my programming could use some tidying.

Comment: `  if depth<maxdepth then begin     a:=binom(depth+1,maxdepth);` it always calls itself

Comment: are you sure you need a recursion here? you can loop digits in binary form to get all required combinations

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your last assignment. Instead of `result[0,1]:=0;` it should be:

```
result[1,0]:=0;
```